# "Segment not found" when using \printbibliography[segment=x] and \includeonly

Tags: biblatex, biber

## Addendum:

@PLK has commented below on the feasibility of this:

> I can't see how this could work - `\includeonly` would have to be
>   changed to be aware of biblatex-specific internals such as the
>   segment/section creation macros in order to track such things in
>   unloaded files.

I am not sure how complicated that is, so I'm offering a small bounty for anyone willing to look into this.

---

There's a conflict between `biblatex`'s `\printbibliography[segment=x]` option to print per-section bibliographies, and the use of `\includeonly`.

As far as I can tell, this is caused by the segment numbers being re-arranged due to the sections not being included. So, if include two sections and the second one uses `\printbibliography[segment=2]`, that will no longer work when you `\includeonly{section2}` because the segment number of that section is now `segment=1`:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Segment '2' not found in Section '0'.
```

This of course is fixable by changing `segment` every time, but that would make the use of `\includeonly` more than cumbersome. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{gob,
  title           = {I've Made a Huge Mistake},
  author          = {Bluth, Gob},
  journal         = {Journal of Magicians},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{michael,
  title           = {Her?},
  author          = {Bluth, Michael},
  journal         = {Sudden Valley},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{tobias,
  title           = {Never-nudism},
  author          = {F{\"u}nke, Tobias},
  journal         = {Blue Man Group},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{section1.tex}
\section{First section}
Check this out~\cite{gob}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=1,]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{section2.tex}
\section{Second section}
Check this out~\cite{michael}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=2,]
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  refsegment=section,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\includeonly{%
  % section1,% % This always works because its segment number is constant at 1.
  section2,%
}

\begin{document}
\include{section1}
\include{section2}
\nocite{tobias}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried playing with this and found `biblatex` advised setting `defernumbers=true`. So I tried that and the references became even crazier. In particular, if I use `defernumbers`, I get reference labels which start at 3 rather than 1. That's without using `\includeonly` at all. I think you might not have this problem using `refsection` but then your references would be local and you couldn't get a useful global bibliography...

Comment: @cfr Yes, the `defernumbers` issue would have been another question actually -- I also get the non-sensical numbering. I am thoroughly confused. `:-)` Also, I am interested in `refsegment` only but I will indeed test `refsection` as well and report back. My intuition about how the problem is caused tells me that it will have the same issue.

Comment: @cfr Oh, wait. `refsection` may work because it resolves the section number automatically using `\printbibliography` instead of, e.g., `\printbibliography[section=2]`. But I think the general issue is still there -- section/segment numbers change when using `\includeonly`.

Comment: I agree about the underlying issue but, yes, that was my thought about `refsection`. I don't understand what is going on with the numbering with `defernumbers`, though. That issue seems to occur without `\includeonly` even...

Comment: @cfr Well, let's see if PLK notices this. Maybe it is a bug. Otherwise, I'll offer a bounty on the question when the option is available and hope for the best. But you are definitely right about `defernumbers` -- it is weird. I'll just post it as a separate question.

Comment: @cfr I posted the new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182593/weird-numbers-with-defernumbers-and-refsegment). Also for anyone else following the discussion.

Comment: I can't see how this could work - `\includeonly` would have to be changed to be aware of biblatex-specific internals such as the segment/section creation macros in order to track such things in unloaded files.

Comment: @PLK I see. Or, I guess, an alternative would be for `\printbibliography` to infer the `refsegment` number automatically like it does for `refsection`. Thanks for looking into this. I'll update the question with your comment and offer a small bounty for the gurus to come to my rescue. `:-)`

Comment: That would be really very hard. Internally, biblatex tags most things with their refsections but not refsegments.

Comment: @PLK No problem at all. Just thinking out loud. I actually already found that using `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]` works quite well. I am not _really_ bothered by the fact that the bibliography numbering/ordering is not what I'd see in the final document (if I clean the auxiliary files and/or rerun `biber` – calls to pdflatex only maintain sanity). At least I can successfully compile the document whilst using `\includeonly`.

Comment: Ah, that's a good solution, yes.

Comment: Did you sort the numbering issue? (I know that has nothing to do with this question. I'm just interested.)

Comment: @cfr PLK commented in the other question that the issue is fixed in the development version of `biblatex` (available on SourceForge I guess), but I haven't had time to test it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=\therefsegment]` instead of explicitly setting the number of the segment, subsequent `pdflatex` invovations do not terminate with a `Segment not found` error.

If the auxiliary files are cleaned or `biber` is re-run, the document still compiles successfully, but the bibliography that is typeset may not be what you would expect to see in the final document (the ordering and/or numbering). Nonetheless, this enables the use of `\includeonly` as there will be no re-compilation errors due to missing segments.