# Weird numbers with defernumbers and refsegment

Tags: biblatex, biber, subdividing

When using `refsegment` without `defernumbers`, I get a warning that I should enable `defernumbers`. When I enable it, the numbering becomes a mess:

[image: Issue]

Specifically, the numbering of the bibliography starts at `x+1` instead of `1`, where `x` is the number of bibliography entries (unique or otherwise) typeset in all `refsegment`s.

Weirdly, the use of, e.g., `refsegment=section` itself does not cause the issue. If the `\printbibliography[segment=x]` commands are commented-out, the numbering starts from `1` as expected.

I also tried `resetnumbers` in the first `\printbibliography`, but nothing changed.

I also posted a question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181425/segment-not-found-when-using-printbibliographysegment-x-and-includeonly) yesterday which gave rise to comments about the `defernumbers` issue. I am not sure whether or how the two are related.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{gob,
  title           = {I've Made a Huge Mistake},
  author          = {Bluth, Gob},
  journal         = {Journal of Magicians},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{michael,
  title           = {Her?},
  author          = {Bluth, Michael},
  journal         = {Sudden Valley},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{tobias,
  title           = {Never-nudism},
  author          = {F{\"u}nke, Tobias},
  journal         = {Blue Man Group},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  refsegment=section,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Check this out~\cite{gob,tobias}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=1,]

\section{Second section}
Check this out~\cite{michael}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=2,]

\nocite{tobias}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you say which version of biblatex you are using? Also, what happens if you run latex again, do the numbers change? Various defernumbers bug fixes were made in fairly recent biblatex updates.

Comment: @PlK I do not know the build numbers but I use a combination of `biblatex` 2.9 and `biber` 1.9, both beta releases, downloaded from SourceForge on May 11th. If the issue has been fixed in a recent release, could you please write a short answer explaining that? Also, any idea if this issue is related to the `\includeonly` issue in the linked question?

Comment: @PLK: Also, no. The numbers do not change if I run latex again.

Comment: Hmm, defernumbers is quite a pain sometimes - I'll have a look at this.

Comment: For what it's worth (a hack), the numbering is correct when you exclude the last `\printbibliography` or if you call it as `\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true]`.

Comment: Please pull the biblatex 3.0 dev version from SF. I think this should be fixed now.

Comment: @PLk I will test this as soon as possible and let you know. Do I also need a new `biber` version? Could you write up a short answer please? It would be great to know if the update also fixes the (related?) issue [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181425/segment-not-found-when-using-printbibliographysegment-x-and-includeonly). Thanks for looking into this on such short notice.

Comment: No new biber version needed for this fix. I'll look at the other issue discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in biblatex. This should be fixed in the 3.0 DEV version on Sourceforge. There is no need to update biber - 1.9 currently works with biblatex 3.0 DEV.